# Activity уничтожается при создании нового экземпляра

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment

Проблема заключается в следующем: У меня есть класс `MainActivity`, класс `FragmentWorkHelper` для работы с фрагментами и класс `VerticalPager` для обработки вертикального скроллинга. В классе `VerticalPager` есть переменная `mNextPage`, которая получает номер следующей страницы во время прокрутки.
Мне нужно, когда переменная `mNextPager` равняется 2, чтобы вызывалась функция в классе `MainActivity` или `FragmentWorkHelper`, которая удалит самый верхний фрагмент.

К сожалению, я не могу вызвать данную функцию следующим образом (данный код я вставляю на момент поднятия пальца):

```
 if (mNextPage == 2){
     MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
     mainActivity.Del();
}
```

Так как активити уничтожается и я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1399)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:616)
        at developers.com.polygon.FragmentWorkHelper.RemoveFrag(FragmentWorkHelper.java:31)
        at developers.com.polygon.MainActivity.Del(MainActivity.java:112)
        at developers.com.polygon.VerticalPager.onTouchEvent(VerticalPager.java:564)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)...
```

**MainActivity**:

```
FragmentWorkHelper helper = new FragmentWorkHelper(this);

    public void Del(){
        helper.RemoveFrag(mtcf);
    }
```

**FragmentWorkHelper**:

```
private final FragmentActivity activity;
FragmentManager fm;

public FragmentWorkHelper(FragmentActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
}

public void ReplaceFrag(Fragment f, int container){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(container, f);
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
}

public void RemoveFrag(Fragment f){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(f);
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
}

public void AddFrag(Fragment f, int container){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(container, f);
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

Как можно обойти данную проблему?

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совершенно непонятно зачем вы создаёте новый экземпляр активити в проблемном методе.

Вам надо просто получить ссылку на действующий экземпляр и в нём уже вызывать нужные вам методы. Если этот участок кода

```
 if (mNextPage == 2){
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
 mainActivity.Del();
 }
```

у вас в классе вашей активити, то вам надо преобразовать его так:

```
 if (mNextPage == 2){
 this.Del();
}
```

Если же он в каком-либо другом классе, то надо в него передать ссылку на вашу активити (также как вы это делаете в конструкторе класса FragmentWorkHelper) и преобразовать (если нужно) к классу MainActivity вот так:

```
if (mNextPage == 2){
MainActivity mainAct=(MainActivity) yoursReferenceToYoursActivity;
mainAct.Del();
}
```

В случае когда этот кусок кода находится внутри ViewGroup, то вы можете получить Context методом getContext() и преобразовать его к MainActivity

```
if (mNextPage == 2){
MainActivity mainAct=(MainActivity) this.getContext();
mainAct.Del();
}
```

Comment: Передать ссылку тоже проблемно. В конструкторе я это сделать не могу, так как, класс 'VerticalPager' наследует ViewGroup и он уже проиницирован. Есть ли другие способы?

Comment: В этом случае вы можете получить Context методом getContext() и преобразовать его к MainActivity. Ответ дополнил.

Comment: Благодарю! Все заработало.